# W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to print data from the database and it prints just fine in the console but I got this error with it and i don't know what is the error to try solve it  And the app does not get any crash it is just print in the console that error can any one help me
this is my code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare3/widgets/header.dart';

final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
}

class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future getUsers() async {
    await usersRef.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc.data());
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, isAppTitle: true),
      body: Text("timeLine"),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the error

```
W/DynamiteModule(25277): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(25277): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(25277): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/d.fluttershare(25277): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
I/flutter (25277): {postsCount: 3, isAdmin: false, username: jane}
I/flutter (25277): {postsCount: 2, isAdmin: true, username: Fred}
```

my gradle App

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.zaidounmohamed.fluttershare3"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that references used in the plugin can't be accessed. It's likely that there was an error installing the package. Try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the packages that you're using. Here's a [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4447) related to this issue.